# BIRT: HTML text split into two columns

Tags: birt

I want to add a multiple page text to a report that is stored in the database as an HTML clob. I would like to split this text into two columns like this:

```
[part 1] [part 2]
[page break]
[part 3] [part 4]
[page break]
[part 5] ...
```

When I use a *Dynamic Text* item the HTML is rendered fine. But I cannot get it to split into two columns. I've tried making it small enough by setting the *width* property, adding it to the *Detail* area of a *List* item and setting the display property of the *List* and the *Dynamic Text* to all possible combinations of *Block* and *Inline*.

Is this even possible with BIRT?

Many thanks in advance.
Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, BIRT doesn't support a newspaper-like layout style.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using iText for both: creating the PDF with the two-column-text and merging it with the PDF generated by BIRT.